# restrict ssh, sftp access on ubuntu 12.04 through iptables or /etc/hosts.allow

Tags: ssh, security, iptables, ubuntu-12.04

I´ve tried to get into restricting access to a ubuntu server but i´m still unsure which way to go. the situation: We want to restrict access for ssh, and sftp to 4 clients with no static ip on a ubuntu 12.04 server. therefore each client has a dyndns account. the server will use a shared firewall, which unfortunately cannot use the dyndns account as allow rules.

The idea: allow access to ssh and sftp in the shared firewall, but block all instead the 4 dyndns accounts on server side.

but what´s the easiest way to achive this?

First solution would be the use of iptabels with this [script](http://dave.thehorners.com/content/view/86/65/): Run by a cronjob it checks for dyndns ips and updates iptable rules with something like:

```
# All connectsion from address 1.2.3.4 to SSH (port 22)
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --source DYNDNS_IP --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Deny all other SSH connections
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

Second solution would be a restricion through denyhosts, f.e.:

```
# /etc/hosts.allow
sshd: client.dyndns.org

# /etc/hosts.deny
sshd: ALL
```

But I am unsure if denyhosts is also able to restrict ftp access. if so, this solution would look a bit easier to manage.

thankful for every idea,

with kind regards,

toni

Comment: If your ftpd was compiled against TCP wrappers then connection will be controlled by hosts.allow/deny. How hard would it be to test? But if you are concerned about security then WTF are you using FTP for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the clients don’t have static IPs, then the next best solution would be to use SSH keys with—or without—passphrases & disabling passwords.  [This is a good primer on SSH keys](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/tips-for-using-ssh-keys.html).

And on the server you would adjust SSH to only accept `publickey` via adjustments to `PreferredAuthentications` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (which is in Ubuntu 12.04). [A good explanation of SSH server-side options is here](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config).

Past that I would still use `iptables` to further restrict ports to make things even more secure.

Comment: If you are at all concerned about security then you should be using keypair authentication. If you're not already doing that then there's probably a lot of other basic prevention measures not implemented on your server. Whether the clients have static or dynamic IPs is irrelevant. With TCP wrappers (but not iptables) you can enforce restrictions based on the IP name independently of the IP address. But there are other solutions too including port knocking and fail2ban

Answer (score 0):

imo, the closer you are to the bottom of the stack, the better for implementing security.  if you block at iptables, the packets never even make it up past layer3/4, so that would be better.   however, the best would be a layered onion security model, with network and host based firewalling, as well as denyhosts/tcpwrappers, and protocol specific security (ie. htaccess rules on apache).

> the server will use a shared firewall, which unfortunately cannot use the dyndns account as allow rules.

you can always replace your perimeter firewall with iptables or pfsense.